# Why isn't Flutter Map updating with changes to coordinates in Consumer?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, fluttermap

I'm trying to display a map in Flutter using flutter_map and update the coordinates using a Consumer. However, the map isn't updating when the coordinates change. If I use a Text widget instead of the map, the change works fine. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it? Here's my code:

```
Consumer<DataManager>(
  builder: (context, manager, child) {
    return MapCoordinateWidget(
      coordinates: LatLng(
        manager.coordinates!.latitude,
        manager.coordinates!.longitude,
      ),
    );
  },
)

class MapCoordinateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MapCoordinateWidget({super.key, required this.coordinates});

  LatLng coordinates;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLight = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light;
    String styleUrl = isLight
        ? "https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
        : "https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png";

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 180,
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            center: coordinates,
            zoom: 10,
            interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.none,
            keepAlive: true,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: "$styleUrl?api_key={api_key}",
              additionalOptions: const {"api_key": stadiaMapsApiKey},
              maxZoom: 20,
              maxNativeZoom: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've already tried setting the keepAlive flag in MapOptions, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can add a `MapController` when you create the map and use the controller's [move](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/MapController/move.html) method when you want to set a new position.

Comment: My flutter app pauses every time I call the .move method. Do I have to implement the MapController in a different way?

Comment: What do you mean 'pauses'? How do you create and use the map controller?

Comment: I added this line of code to my Flutter Map: `mapController: manager.controller,` and initialized the controller inside a class that extends ChangeNotifier: `MapController controller = MapController();` When I call `controller.move(LatLng(46, 32), 15);` my app gets stuck and the screen freezes.

Comment: I would rather suggest to create the map controller in the widget itself, for example in an `initState` method, since it is attached to the widget's life cycle. But I still don't know what kind of pause are you experiencing. Are you sure the move is successful? (it returns true if yes. For example if the zoom level is outside allowed it can fail and return false).

Comment: No, the move isn't successful and I don't get any value returned.

Comment: And how should I update the shown coordinates, if I initialize my MapController inside the Stateful Widget itself?

Comment: You want to update it from a different widget? You have to access the map controller, for example you can save it's value in a provider.

Comment: Now, after initializing the MapController within the map widget itself and then saving the value within a class, the map updates with the move method. It seems to have been due to this. Is it possible to create an even smoother transition between the two different maps?

Comment: Good news. With this package the `move` method is your only option if I remember correctly. Others maps, like Google for example, can animate when the center is moved.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Should I mark a comment with a flag, to show others which answer was helpful?

Comment: No need, you are welcome.

Comment: @MultiMedia Please see https://github.com/TesteurManiak/flutter_map_animations for animated movement. Also the example app has a basic implementation.